# Converting Euro to Rupees in India

Tags: india, foreign-exchange, eur-euro, inr-indian-rupee

I saved 1000 Euros during my internship in France, and brought them back to India in cash. It has been a year since then, and I want to deposit it in my bank account now. I was told by the bank that I should have done it within 6 months of my arrival, and they cannot accept it now.

Can't I officially convert the money to INR anymore?

Comment: You can always convert foreign cash at a currency conversion kiosk at a major airport, or one in major cities.

Comment: @TainToTain Do they have any requirements? Do I get an invoice?

Comment: Why does the bank care when you received the Euros?

Comment: I was told that they require a visa arrival stamp of within 6 months.  Perhaps some regulation by the Reserve Bank of India. I don't know the exact details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to convert this officially. As per RBI regulation an individual can hold upto USD 2000 eq for an unlimited period of time. See the [point 14 on RBI FAQ's for Fx.](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FAQView.aspx?Id=11)

Comment: Will I have to convert it at a money exchange rather than a bank?

Comment: @Miheer You should be able to do this at Bank. Most small branches would shy away as they don't fully understand the regulation and play safe.